# how to override main containers max-width using css

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress blog template, which has a main container:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1040px;
```

On one page I need to have an image, that will be a full size background image: 100% of available width. But no matter what I do, I can't get the image to go outside of the template main container (1040px). Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you add the background to the `<body>`?

Comment: Hashem has a point... I don't know if you're able to add javascript on the blog html, but if you do, you can add that image to the body with jquery.

Comment: cause that needs to be on one subpage out of many. and it won't be just one image, but rather a couple of images 100% width one after another separated with some other containers between them.

Comment: Do you have to achieve this in CSS? Is it possible to modify your template?

Answer (score 2):

While its possible using absolute positioning to get an image outside the container it was made in, why would you want to do that when you can just use CSS backgrounds!

So I'm assuming you have a container inside a bigger container.... what you want to do is set the image to be the background of the bigger container like this (i'm doing this assuming the container it is in is the whole page... but it can be any div) :

```
html { 
  background: url(YOURIMAGE.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Edit** Ok I see what you want to do. You want a nested div to have 100% page width right?

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.item {
    
    height: 300px;
    background-color:#0000FF;
    width:100%;
    
}

.fullblock {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height:300px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="fullblock">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This will allow your nested div to burst out of its container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chase, but I've tried that.

The issue is that I have a smaller container (1040px max width) that is my main theme container and I don't want to temper with that. 

But I want to have few larger containers (full width) INSIDE of that smaller container, that will actually have 100% width, and not be limited with 1040px.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It didn't work, cause my main div from template still was giving set width and all the 100% "below" were 100% of 1040. But I started the code of the page with a couple of </div> and that helped with my problem, so that's awesome :)

Comment: It worked! I only used `<div class="fullblock">` bit of the code, but it worked. I guess the `z-index` part did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up question (I know this response is from a couple of years ago): It seems that when I use the `<div class="fullback">` code, it overrides other properties on the page--the page title, for example, appears again (it was suppressed with `.entry-header {display: none;}` ) Any further tip on how to approach understanding this bit would be greatly appreciated.